# Convergence in distribution of the log-Gamma distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

Suppose $X$ has density $f(x)=\exp(kx-e^x)/\Gamma(k)$, $x>0$, for some parameter $k>0$. Then the moment-generating function of $X$ has the form
$$
M_X(\theta)=\frac{\Gamma(\theta+k)}{\Gamma(k)}.
$$
I want to show that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}M_{X^*}(\theta)=\exp(\theta^2/2),
$$
where $X^*=\sqrt{k}(X-\log k)$ using Stirling's formula:
$$
\log \Gamma(k)=-k+\left(k-\tfrac12\right)\log k+\log\sqrt{2\pi}+O(k^{-1}).
$$
Now
$$
M_{X^*}(\theta)={\rm E}[\exp(\theta\sqrt{k}(X-\log k))]=\exp(-\theta\sqrt{k}\log k)M_X(\theta\sqrt{k})
$$
and hence
$$
\log M_{X^*}(\theta)=-\theta\sqrt{k}\log k+\log \Gamma(\theta\sqrt{k}+k)-\log \Gamma(k).
$$
Using Stirling's formula, I obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\log M_{X^*}(\theta)=&-\theta\sqrt{k}\log k-(\theta\sqrt{k}+k)+(\theta\sqrt{k}+k-\tfrac12)\log(\theta\sqrt{k}+k)+\log\sqrt{2\pi}+O(k^{-1})\\
&+k-\left(k-\tfrac12\right)\log k-\log\sqrt{2\pi}-O(k^{-1})\\
\end{align}
$$
but nothing really seems to cancel out. How do I proceed from here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the decomposition $\log(\theta\sqrt{k}+k)=\log(k)+\log(1+\theta/\sqrt{k})$ and the expansion $\log(1+\theta/\sqrt{k})=\theta/\sqrt{k}-\theta^2/(2k)+o(1/k)$ then watch the simplifications happening.

As a way of confirmation, one can note that the density $f_k$ of $X^*$ is such that $f_k(x)=c_k\mathrm e^{-u_k(x)}$ with
$$
c_k=\frac{\mathrm e^{-k}k^{k-1/2}}{\Gamma(k)},\qquad u_k(x)=k(\mathrm e^{x/\sqrt{k}}-1)-\sqrt{k}x,
$$
and that $c_k\to\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $u_k(x)\to\frac12x^2$ when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: That's neat! Thank you. Shouldn't it be $o(k^{-3/2})$ though?

Comment: You are welcome. The error term might well be $o(1/k^{3/2})$ but one needs only it to be $o(1/k)$.

Comment: But wouldn't $(\theta\sqrt{k}+k-\tfrac12)\log(\theta\sqrt{k}+k)$ then have a non-vanishing term by multiplying $k$ with the $o(1/k)$ term?

Comment: Nope, $o(1/k)$ is just what is needed to become $o(1)$ when multiplied by $(\theta\sqrt{k}+k-\frac12)$ since $(\theta\sqrt{k}+k-\frac12)=O(k)$. And $o(1)$ means exactly "which disappears in the limit because it goes to zero".

Comment: Ah, I think I was confusing $o$ and $O$. Thanks again.